# Concatenate & Date format in VBA

Tags: vba, date, format

I have a set of formulae in VBA which automatic concatenates and gives the value something like above "`2 1`".
Whenever the second no is negative the output changes in date format. Can anyone help to get in the normal format like above?

Let's say in one Sheet I've Input data in Cells(1,5) = 1 and Cells(5,5) = 2.00 and the concatenate output should be "`1 2.00`" what I'm getting is "`1 2`" Is it possible to achieve the decimal "`.00`" when concatenated?
`Cells(i + 20, k + 1) = Cells(n, j + 1) & " " & Cells(i + 2, j + 1)` ' code i've used:
[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and the formula that is related. We can't see what you have and no idea where to begin.

Comment: Your cell needs to have text format before: `Range.NumberFormat = "@"`

Comment: Sorry @PatricK for not being descriptive. I figured above and caught in some other similar to the above problem.:                            
Let's say in one Sheet I've Input data in Cells(1,5) = 1 and Cells(5,5) = 2.00 and the concatenate output should be "1 2.00" what I'm getting is "1 2" It is possible to achieve the decimal ".00" when concatenated?                                                    Cells(i + 20, k + 1) = Cells(n, j + 1) & " " & Cells(i + 2, j + 1)   ' code i've used

Comment: Thanks @Asger for the response

Comment: if you want exactly what is displayed in the cell rather than value, use `.Text` instead of `.Value`.

Comment: Thanks @PatricK its worked perfectly fine.